# File upload in java web application shows file not found exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, io, filenotfoundexception

I am developing a web application using jsp and servlets. I am trying to upload a file  and then process the data of that file. for this purpose my jsp code is

```
<form action="LoadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="50" accept=".doc, .docx, .txt"/>
     <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Check Now" name="upload" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

Java servlet named "LoadFile.java" contains the following code in processRequest method

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
        String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

        OutputStream outStream = null;
        InputStream filecontent = null;
        final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(File.separator
                    + fileName));

            filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
            writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                    + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                    + "location.");
            writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

        }
```

Whenever I tries to upload a file, it gives the FileNotFoundExceptin.
What do I need to do?

Comment: Who is throwing that exception? FileOutputStream constructor?

Comment: Please give us the exact stacktrace of the FNFE

Comment: Access is denied message is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Web Application `WEB-INF` folder create a folder called `files` and change the code of `FileOutputStream` as below.

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(request.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/")+ "files"+ File.separator
                    + fileName));
```